# Populate JSON Data into RecyclerView with Infinite Scroll

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, retrofit, infinite-scroll

I am using [this](https://github.com/sevakkalpesh315/RxJava_Retrofit-Integration) Retrofit Demo to parse JSON and [this](https://github.com/jayrambhia/FooterLoaderAdapterDemo) one to implement infinite scrolling in RecyclerView

I have successfully parsed JSON data, but unable to populate that data into RecyclerView

You may download complete code [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6HxxqmbPu1BRFlJRUdyelBUUEE/view?usp=sharing) to check at your end

Log says:

```
03-10 18:15:39.872 24744-24766/app.retrofit_chucknorries D/Retrofit: <--- HTTP 200 http://api.icndb.com/jokes/jokenumber (7112ms)
03-10 18:15:39.873 24744-24766/app.retrofit_chucknorries D/Retrofit: Date: Thu, 10 Mar 2016 12:45:40 GMT
03-10 18:15:39.873 24744-24766/app.retrofit_chucknorries D/Retrofit: Server: Apache
03-10 18:15:39.873 24744-24766/app.retrofit_chucknorries D/Retrofit: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
03-10 18:15:39.873 24744-24766/app.retrofit_chucknorries D/Retrofit: Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
03-10 18:15:39.874 24744-24766/app.retrofit_chucknorries D/Retrofit: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
03-10 18:15:39.874 24744-24766/app.retrofit_chucknorries D/Retrofit: Content-Type: application/json
03-10 18:15:39.875 24744-24766/app.retrofit_chucknorries D/Retrofit: OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
03-10 18:15:39.876 24744-24766/app.retrofit_chucknorries D/Retrofit: OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1457613939563
03-10 18:15:39.876 24744-24766/app.retrofit_chucknorries D/Retrofit: OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1457613939824
03-10 18:15:40.860 24744-24766/app.retrofit_chucknorries D/Retrofit: { "type": "success", "value": [ { "id": 1, "joke": "Chuck Norris uses ribbed condoms inside out, so he gets the pleasure.", "categories": ["explicit"] }, { "id": 2, "joke": "MacGyver can build an airplane out of gum and paper clips. Chuck Norris can kill him and take it.", "categories": [] }, { "id": 584, "joke": "Only Chuck Norris shuts down websites without due process, not SOPA or PIPA.", "categories": [] } ]  }
03-10 18:15:40.871 24744-24766/app.retrofit_chucknorries D/Retrofit: <--- END HTTP (79106-byte body)
03-10 18:15:41.740 24744-24744/app.retrofit_chucknorries D/list::-: [app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420c3388, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420c3730, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420c3a10, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420c3ce8, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420c4060, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420c43a0, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420c4690, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420c4900, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420c4d40, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420c4ff8, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420c52f0, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420c5650, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420c59a0, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420c5d40, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420c6c58, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420c7080, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420c7310, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420c75a0, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420c7930, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420c7c88, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420c8320, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420c8690, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420c8940, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420c8cc8, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420c9048, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420c92c0, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420c95d8, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420c9908, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420c9ca0, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420ca160, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420ca3f0, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420ca6e0, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420ca9a0, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420cad98, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420cb030, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420cb310, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420cb5c0, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420cb878, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420cbb50, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420cbf08, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420cc208, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420cc5b0, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420cc8d0, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420ccc18, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420cceb0, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420cd228, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420cd500, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420cd878, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420cdb50, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420cde28, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420ce138, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420ce410, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420ce798, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420ceac0, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420ceda0, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420cf070, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420cf368, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420cf6a0, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420cf9f8, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420cfd88, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420d0058, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420d05b0, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420d0858, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420d0c10, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420d0ed8, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420d11a0, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420d15e8, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420d1858, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420d1b30, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420d1d90, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420d20d8, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420d2f38, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420d31e8, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420d3660, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420d3908, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420d3b90, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420d3e88, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420d41b0, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420d4468, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420d4768, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420d5640, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420d58e0, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420d5bc0, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.Value@420d5ed8, app.retrofit_chucknorries.model.V
03-10 18:15:41.751 24744-24744/app.retrofit_chucknorries D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 0)
03-10 18:15:41.752 24744-24744/app.retrofit_chucknorries D/GraphicBuffer: close handle(0x54f4e008) (w:480 h:144 f:1)
03-10 18:15:41.752 24744-24744/app.retrofit_chucknorries D/GraphicBuffer: close handle(0x555eab38) (w:480 h:144 f:1)
03-10 18:15:41.753 24744-24744/app.retrofit_chucknorries D/GraphicBuffer: close handle(0x55631d30) (w:480 h:144 f:1)
03-10 18:15:41.754 24744-24744/app.retrofit_chucknorries D/GraphicBuffer: close handle(0x55499d60) (w:480 h:144 f:1)
03-10 18:15:41.801 24744-24744/app.retrofit_chucknorries D/app.retrofit_chucknorries.MainActivity$3: Called unsubscribe OnPause()
03-10 18:15:41.826 24744-24744/app.retrofit_chucknorries V/InputMethodManager: onWindowFocus: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{41e54a80 VFED.... .F....I. 0,0-480,678 #7f0c005d app:id/list} softInputMode=272 first=true flags=#1810100
03-10 18:15:41.828 24744-24744/app.retrofit_chucknorries V/InputMethodManager: START INPUT: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{41e54a80 VFED.... .F....I. 0,0-480,678 #7f0c005d app:id/list} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@421b0f98 controlFlags=#105
03-10 18:15:59.036 24744-24744/app.retrofit_chucknorries D/app.retrofit_chucknorries.MainActivity: Called unsubscribe OnPause() done
03-10 18:15:59.037 24744-24744/app.retrofit_chucknorries D/ActivityThread: ACT-AM_ON_PAUSE_CALLED ActivityRecord{41e15050 token=android.os.BinderProxy@41e147d0 {app.retrofit_chucknorries/app.retrofit_chucknorries.MainActivity}}
03-10 18:15:59.051 24744-24744/app.retrofit_chucknorries D/ActivityThread: ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@41e147d0
03-10 18:15:59.056 24744-24744/app.retrofit_chucknorries V/InputMethodManager: START INPUT: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{41e54a80 VFED.... .F....I. 0,0-480,678 #7f0c005d app:id/list} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@421b44b0 controlFlags=#100
03-10 18:15:59.157 24744-24744/app.retrofit_chucknorries V/ActivityThread: Finishing stop of ActivityRecord{41e15050 token=android.os.BinderProxy@41e147d0 {app.retrofit_chucknorries/app.retrofit_chucknorries.MainActivity}}: show=true win=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow@41e21f50
03-10 18:15:59.157 24744-24744/app.retrofit_chucknorries D/ActivityThread: ACT-STOP_ACTIVITY_SHOW handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@41e147d0
03-10 18:16:40.820 24744-24812/app.retrofit_chucknorries D/dalvikvm: threadid=14: exiting
03-10 18:16:40.821 24744-24812/app.retrofit_chucknorries D/dalvikvm: threadid=14: bye!
03-10 18:16:41.702 24744-24766/app.retrofit_chucknorries D/dalvikvm: threadid=13: exiting
03-10 18:16:41.711 24744-24766/app.retrofit_chucknorries D/dalvikvm: threadid=13: bye!
03-10 18:21:54.022 24744-24744/app.retrofit_chucknorries D/GraphicBuffer: create handle(0x554a7630) (w:480, h:800, f:1)
```

May I know where I am doing ?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    IJokes apiJokes;
    private DemoAdapter mAdapter;
    private List<Value> mJokestList;
    private Subscription  resumeSub;
    private Handler mHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        resumeSub= apiJokes.getJokes()
                .cache()
                .timeout(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .retry(1)
                .doOnUnsubscribe(new Action0() {
                    @Override
                    public void call() {
                        Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Called unsubscribe OnPause()");
                    }
                })
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Action1<JokesModel>() {
                               @Override
                               public void call(JokesModel jokesModel) {
                                   mJokestList = jokesModel.getValue();
                                   Log.d("list::-", String.valueOf(mJokestList));
                                   displayGistList(mJokestList);

                               }
                           }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
                               @Override
                               public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                                   Log.e(getClass().getName(), "ERROR: " + throwable.getMessage());
                                   throwable.printStackTrace();

                               }
                           }
                );
    }
    private void createGithubClient() {
        if (apiJokes == null) {
            apiJokes = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                    .setEndpoint(Constants.BASE_URL)
                    .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                    .build()
                    .create(IJokes.class);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recycler_main);

        mHandler = new Handler();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerViewScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollUp() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollDown() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                loadMoreData();
            }
        });

        createGithubClient();

    }

    public void displayGistList(final List<Value> gists) {
        if (gists.size()>0 && mRecyclerView!=null) {
            mAdapter = new DemoAdapter(MainActivity.this);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            hidePDialog();
        }
    }
    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Called unsubscribe OnPause() done");
        resumeSub.unsubscribe();
    }

    private void loadMoreData() {

        mAdapter.showLoading(true);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        // Load data after delay
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("size::-", ""+mJokestList.size());
                List<Value> newItems = getData(mJokestList.size());
                mJokestList.addAll(newItems);
                mAdapter.setItems(mJokestList); // No need of this
                mAdapter.showLoading(false);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, 1500);

    }

    // I GUESS HERE I HAVE TO MAKE CHANGE
    private List<Value> getData(int start) {
        List<Value> items = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=start; i<start+12; i++) {
            items.add(new Value(i, "user " + i));
        }

        return items;
    }
}
```

**Value.java:**

```
public class Value {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("joke")
    @Expose
    private String joke;
    @SerializedName("categories")
    @Expose
    private List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();

    // unable to understand this -- I forced to create this one
    public Value(int i, String s) {
    }


    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The id
     */
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param id
     * The id
     */
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The joke
     */
    public String getJoke() {
        return joke;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param joke
     * The joke
     */
    public void setJoke(String joke) {
        this.joke = joke;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The categories
     */
    public List<String> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param categories
     * The categories
     */
    public void setCategories(List<String> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

As suggested by *@david.mihola*, I used **mAdapter.setItems(gists);** in `displayGistList(...)` and now I am `getting data` in RecyclerView

**QUESTION**

Still, I am getting *all 584 records* in `onCreate()`, whereas, I would like to show *first 20 records* in `onCreate()` then using infinite scroll `next 10 records` on each call

At the end it shows progress and I get this:

```
03-11 10:23:14.061 13211-13211/app.retrofit_chucknorries E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: app.retrofit_chucknorries, PID: 13211
                                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
                                                                               at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
                                                                               at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:139)
                                                                               at app.retrofit_chucknorries.adapter.DemoAdapter.bindYourViewHolder(DemoAdapter.java:38)
                                                                               at app.retrofit_chucknorries.adapter.FooterLoaderAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FooterLoaderAdapter.java:58)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5277)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5310)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4568)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4461)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1962)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1371)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1334)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:563)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2847)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3145)
                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15140)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4866)
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15140)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4866)
                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15140)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4866)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:437)
                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15140)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4866)
                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15140)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4866)
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15140)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4866)
                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15140)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4866)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2336)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2042)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1208)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6274)
                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**FooterLoaderAdapter.java:**

```
public abstract class FooterLoaderAdapter<T> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    protected boolean showLoader;
    private static final int VIEWTYPE_ITEM = 1;
    private static final int VIEWTYPE_LOADER = 2;

    protected List<T> mItems;
    protected LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public FooterLoaderAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == VIEWTYPE_LOADER) {

            // Your Loader XML view here
            View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.loader_item_layout, viewGroup, false);

            // Your LoaderViewHolder class
            return new LoaderViewHolder(view);

        } else if (viewType == VIEWTYPE_ITEM) {
            return getYourItemViewHolder(viewGroup);
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid ViewType: " + viewType);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

        // Loader ViewHolder
        if (viewHolder instanceof LoaderViewHolder) {
            LoaderViewHolder loaderViewHolder = (LoaderViewHolder)viewHolder;
            if (showLoader) {
                loaderViewHolder.mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                loaderViewHolder.mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            return;
        }

        bindYourViewHolder(viewHolder, position);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        // If no items are present, there's no need for loader
        if (mItems == null || mItems.size() == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        // +1 for loader
        return mItems.size() + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        // loader can't be at position 0
        // loader can only be at the last position
        if (position != 0 && position == getItemCount() - 1) {

            // id of loader is considered as -1 here
            return -1;
        }
        return getYourItemId(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        // loader can't be at position 0
        // loader can only be at the last position
        if (position != 0 && position == getItemCount() - 1) {
            return VIEWTYPE_LOADER;
        }

        return VIEWTYPE_ITEM;
    }

    public void showLoading(boolean status) {
        showLoader = status;
    }

    public void setItems(List<T> items) {
        mItems = items;
    }

    public abstract long getYourItemId(int position);
    public abstract RecyclerView.ViewHolder getYourItemViewHolder(ViewGroup parent);
    public abstract void bindYourViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position);

}
```

**DemoAdapter.java:**

```
public class DemoAdapter extends FooterLoaderAdapter<Value> {

    ...    
    @Override
    public long getYourItemId(int position) {
        return mItems.get(position).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getYourItemViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
        return new DemoViewHolder(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.card_row, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void bindYourViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder instanceof DemoViewHolder) {
            DemoViewHolder viewHolder = (DemoViewHolder)holder;
            Log.d("title::-", mItems.get(position).getJoke());
            viewHolder.mUsernameView.setText(mItems.get(position).getJoke());
        }
    }

    public class DemoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @Bind(R.id.name) TextView mUsernameView;
        public DemoViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting the values in the list - gists?

Comment: @DroidWormNarendra I think yes, I have uploaded code to Google Drive and above shared that link.. I have tried my best, you may try at your end ...

Comment: why it has been downvoted ?

Comment: don't know, but shouldn't be downvoted.

Comment: Your `loadMoreData` is probably never called, right? And, consequently, no items are ever added to your adapter. I think you should just put all the jokes you loaded with your initial request into the Adapter right away (i. e. put a `mAdapter.setItems(gists)` into your `displayGistList`).

Comment: @david.mihola thanks now I am getting data in RecyclerView, but still getting all 584 records in onCreate() check my updated code

Answer (score 1):

Wow. A lot of things going on. You're using RxJava, Retrofit and few more things to mash up something. You've got the whole concept incorrect of infinite loader. There are two scenarios.

- You already have the data in your memory and just need to display it.
- You don't have the data and you need to load it from the server / database / disk

What I would suggest is something like this.

```
public interface ApiProvider {
    Observable<List<MyData>> getData(int offset, int limit);
}
```

And your implementation for REST Api based data provider,

```
public class RESTApiProvider implements ApiProvider {

    public RESTApiProvider() {
        // Initialize Retrofit service provider
    }
    @Override
    public Observable<List<MyData>> getData(int offset, int limit) {
        // Retrofit provides data
    }
}
```

In your activity,

```
private void loadMoreData(int offset, int limit) {
    mAdapter.showLoading(true);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    Observable<List<MyData>> observable = restApiProvider.getData(offset, limit);

    observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
              .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
              .subscribe(new Action1<MyData>() {
                           @Override
                           public void call(List<MyData> data) {                                 
                               mItems.addAll(data);
                               mAdapter.setData(mItems);
                               mAdapter.showLoading(false);
                               mAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
                           }
                       }); 

}
```